# Determining if Thread is sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading

I was wondering how I could know if a thread is sleeping or not.
I searched around and I gathered some information, form those information I wrote a method       *isSleeping():boolean*  that I think I can put in a class to determine if the thread is    sleeping or not. I just want to know what I might have missed. Note: I am not experienced 0 days of experience.

```
//isSleeping returns true if this thread is sleeping and false otherwise.
public boolean isSleeping(){
    boolean state = false;
    StackTraceElement[] threadsStackTrace = this.getStackTrace();

    if(threadsStackTrace.length==0){
        state = false;
    }
    if(threadsStackTrace[0].getClassName().equals("java.lang.Thread")&&
            threadsStackTrace[0].getMethodName().equals("Sleep")){
        state = true;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change "Sleep" -> "sleep". Besides you should not take stacktrace on `this`, your method should accept a Thread parameter. Consider this

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if(t.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName().equals("java.lang.Thread")&&
            t.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().equals("sleep")){
        System.out.println("sleeping");
    }
```

output

```
sleeping
```

Comment: This is better than my solution. You just need to prepare for non-sleeping status. It throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Sure, it was just to demonstrate that OP idea worked

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if [Thread#getState()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState%28%29) has a `TIMED_WAITING` state. if using this approach care should be taken to ensure that you havent just called `Object#wait`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea, I didn't check, but I think it would work:

You can extend the thread and override the sleep to switch a state.
Something like this:

```
 @Override
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos)
throws InterruptedException {
   SLEEPMARKER = true;
   super.sleep(millis, nanos);
   SLEEPMARKER = false;
}

 @Override
public static void sleep(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
   SLEEPMARKER = true;
   super.sleep(millis);
   SLEEPMARKER = false;
}
```

Then you need only the marker and a getter for that.

```
public static boolean SLEEPMARKER = false;
public static boolean isSleeping(){
   return SLEEPMARKER;
}
```

Comment: So this won't work on threads you don't create...  including main.  I don't know how easy it is to get under the hood enough to change the JVM to use this on start-up and route all thread creation through it.  Furthermore you will be permanently stuck in a sleep state on interrupt.